# Camerawesome example throwing error Flutter

Tags: flutter, binding, camera

I am trying to run the camerawesome example for the flutter camera. However, when I do that, it throws an error. I tried installing it separately and including it in my project, however, the same error occurs. Do you have any idea if the plugin is deprecated or if there is any known solution to this?

The error that I am receiving has nothing to do with the plugin itself, but with a widget from its implementation. Here is the error message:

/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camerawesome-0.3.3/lib/camerapreview.dart:139:29: Error: Method 'addObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
  Try calling using ?. instead.
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camerawesome-0.3.3/lib/camerapreview.dart:189:29: Error: Method 'removeObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
  Try calling using ?. instead.
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72819007/edit) and copy-and-paste the `C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart`?

Comment: Hello! This is an official flutter lib file. Unfortunately, it is too big to be written in the body.

Comment: What `flutter --version` outputs to you?

Comment: Just managed to fix the issue. I was running flutter 2.10 and updated it to flutter 3. This solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to upgrade flutter version to 3 since I was running flutter 2.10.